# Sending Gmail in .Net Using oAuth2 Authentication [Rephrased]

Tags: .net, gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0

I have written a .Net app in VB that requests access to a user's gmail contacts. It uses oAuth2 to do this in the manner described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2. It uses these libraries: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/wiki/OAuth2

The application has a database of names and addresses. If the user creates a new contact in the application it is also created in their Google contacts, automatically.

This is successful. I use oAuth2 as the authentication process as recommended by Google so the user's password is not stored by the .net application.

I would also like to use the user's google account to send email from within the .Net app. However, I can find no way of doing this using oAuth2 to authenticate the request. The only examples I can find don't use oAuth2 and require the application to have access to the user's password, like this: http://www.jarloo.com/gmail-in-c

Any help on how to send gmail from within the .net app using oAuth2 authentication would be much appreciated.

Comment: .Net's SmtpClient does not support OAuth; you'll need to use a third-party option.

Comment: I can see this link: [https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_libraries) which provides libraries for Java, Python and PHP but cannot find any options for .NET.

Comment: http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth-with-gmail

Comment: @SLaks This works very well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you find any solution using Google mail dll? (Basically without using 3rd party services)